# jquery Modal dialog Get value of input type text by id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this code in my php file

```
$text .= '      <input type="text" name="prefix" value="'.htmlspecialchars($e1['prefix']).'" maxlength="20" class="inputListForm" id="prefix"/>';
```

i want to get the value of the input type text

and this is my code :

```
var prefix = $('#prefix').get(0).value;
console.log(prefix);
```

i also try `document.getElementById("prefix");`

but still no result

Comment: Place your `<script>` as `last-child` of `<body>`

Comment: What you have shown should work absolutely fine.  Is your code in a document.ready handler? Do you have multiple elements with the same `id`? A demo of the issue would help a lot.

Comment: Do you have any other fields that have the same ID?

Comment: By the way what is printed in `console` ?

Comment: No printed on console, just blank

Comment: i also dont have fields that have the same ID

Comment: Did you check the value of `$e1['prefix']` ?

Comment: yes the value is 123 `value=123`

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you use jQuery syntax for code you want get value: 
for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var prefix = $('#prefix').val();
   console.log(prefix); 

});
```

Make sure you have added jquery Library and it will not conflict this .

If you want to get this value on button click option than you must call action event as bellow:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function (e) { 
      var prefix = $('#prefix').val();
       console.log(prefix); 
   });
});
```

In this you also need this get value between jQuery syntax. 
Hope you got your solution.